# How to change one word

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database I have several rows of images that are tagged and I have to change one of the tags for all the images.

The tags look like this `tag1,tag2,tag3` in one row.

How can I single out so that I can change only "tag2"? For example "tag2" turns into "tag4" while tag1 and tag3 should not change at all.

I can't get my head around this at all.

there are 1000 images and i can only change 1 at a time but i need to change this for all 1000 images in one mysql query if possible.

Comment: I suggest you add an example of what your database looks like, and what code you are currently using to change 1 tag at a time. This will give the community significantly more information to help you with

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET tags = REPLACE(tags, 'tag2', 'tag4')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must take into account that `tag2` could be part of another tag and to avoid unnecessary updates check if `tag2` is really part of the column:

```
update tablename
set col = trim(both ',' from replace(concat(',', col, ','), ',tag2,', ',tag4,'))
where concat(',', col, ',') like '%,tag2,%'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5HyXtBo7yGQhrMoFQcEg8C/1)

Comment: Will that change tag 2 even if there are more stuff around? there can be More then one tag before and after tag2.

Comment: This code changes tag2 to tag4 only if it is not part of another tag. Meaning this tag1,tag2,tag3 will be changed to tag1,tag4,tag3 but tag1,tag2abc,tag3 will not be changed because tag2 is only part of a tag and not a tag.

Comment: See the demo and check it